# Teradata 16 Issues

Tags: teradata

We recently upgraded our Teradata version to 16 and since then we are facing few spool space issues. Before the query was consuming less then 200GB and now it consumes more than 1.5TB. We then started optimizing the query and we modified a part of the query

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.XX, C.YY  FROM TABLE1  A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON  A.DD = B.EE
INNER JOIN TABLE3 C ON  C.FF = B.GG
GROUP BY 1,2)
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.XX, C.YY  FROM TABLE1  A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON  A.DD = B.EE
INNER JOIN (SELECT FF, YY FROM TABLE3 GROUP BY 1,2) C 
ON  C.FF = B.GG
GROUP BY 1,2)
```

After modification the query runs within 200GB. Could someone please explain as why we face such issues after upgrade? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes the indexes were rebuilt

Comment: @MitchWheat: There's no need to rebuild indexes in Teradata, in fact there's not even syntax for i :-)

Comment: Which prvious release did you upgrade from? There are usually a few queries with problems after an upgrade, mainly because the optimizer got "smarter" and switches to a different plan. In many cases this can be fixed be checking/adding statistics.

Comment: @dnoeth - Our previous version was 15.1

Comment: And the new one is actually 16.0,  not 16.10/20?

Comment: @dnoeth. We have upgraded from 15.10 to 16.10

Comment: This might happen for any upgrade, even if you do regression testing on a dev system before. You should check DBQL to compare old & new plan.